# ASP.NET C# Generate own UserID

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am completely new to ASP.NET and C#. I want to create my own `userID` which will comprise of the person's initials and a number. Can I do this using a function, for instance where I run a database query

```
Select count for users where UserID like "MM%"
```

and then use the count and increment it and merge it on to my initials and then return that as my `userID`. So that if the count came back as `10` my new `userID` would be `MM11`.

Comment: What happens when a user deletes their account? You'll potentially end up with dupe ids without extra checks.

Comment: What if someone's name changes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to Generate an ID on the WebApp/page rather than creating it directly on database itself using SQL , It would make the ID Generation a lot easier and simpler as well as validate it easily.

Steps would be :

1. Check for Similar entries with initials in database via Select query.
2. Generate Initials + appropriate random number within specified bounds until Generated ID is not within Already existing ID's in Previous Select query Results.
3. Add Record to database.

Answer (score 0):

most commonly, IDs are integers, auto-increment fields.